# Horiztonal Scrolling Page

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a horizontal scrolling page and I was wondering what the best technique is to having each content div centered on the page instead of left aligned as I keep getting with all of the examples I come across in Google.

I have tried this code with no luck:

```
var wind = $(window).width();
    $(".section").width(wind);
    $(window).resize(function(){
    var windRe = $(window).width();
    $(".section").width(windRe);
});
```

[Here is the example site](http://www.fourthfloorcreative.com/secret.php).  Right now I am just trying to get the content to become centered.  Obviously if it wasn't scrolling horizontally I could just `margin:0 auto`.

I am looking for this effect: http://refreshperspective.com/CLIENTS/unboxed/products.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking to do will require a wrapping container with overflow set to hidden. You then will have children who will have their own content (the content will be centered off their parent)

I created this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hdZB/ (click the "Animate" button!) It's super simple and is ready for more advanced jQuery (to handle the animation/looping!) But the basic concept is there!

Good luck!

Comment: Simply Awesome!  I applied some basic Jquery to that and now my page runs like a dream! http://fourthfloorcreative.com/secret.php